# Copy luminance/alpha texture to texture in GLES

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to copy a luminance texture to a luminance texture. More specifically, I'm trying to extend a single channel texture in memory with another texture.

My current steps:

```
create FBO with Luminance format, new width and height.

bind FBO.

render the textures concatenated.

unbind FBO

create Luminance texture the size of FBO

bind FBO with Luminance texture

render FBO's previous texture

unbind FBO
```

However the GLES 2.0 docs state, that FBO's can't render to luminance textures. How do I work with single byte textures then? Is it possible for me to copy luminance textures on the gpu anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using RGBA_4444, which is 2 bytes, so an increase of 100%, but still acceptable.